# Cómo puedo hacer para crear una página por cada categoria de un blog de forma dinámica?

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un blog.
De momento he listado los post, con etiquetas, imágenes, etc. Hasta ahí todo bien.

Que al hacer click en cada etiqueta apunte a una `url` lo he hecho con `explode` y `trim`

```
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $miconsulta)) {
    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        
        // Enlace en la etiqueta con el nombre de la etiqueta como URL
        if (!empty($registro['Etiquetas'])) {
            $etiquetas = explode(",", $registro['Etiquetas']);
            foreach ($etiquetas as $etiqueta) {
                echo '<a id="tagLink" href="etiqueta=' . trim($etiqueta) . '"> <p class="card-text tag">' . trim($etiqueta) . '</p></a>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Entonces, ahora que me devuelve la url, por ejemplo: `blog/etiqueta=etiqueta1`

¿Qué tengo que hacer para que se muestre esa página? no sé cómo hacer para no tener que crear una página por etiqueta de forma manual. Me explico?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Buenas, David, bienvenido al sitio. La idea no es crear una página por cada categoría, sino una sola página que reciba esa categoría como argumento (en la URL, por ejemplo) y que liste aquellas entradas que pertenecen a esa categoría. En tu código de arriba, el href sería algo así: href="lista.php?etiqueta=" ... y lo mismo que tienes ahora. Puedes reusar la página que ya tienes y si viene ese parámetro en la URL aplicar un filtro extra a la consulta que recupera los artículos.

Comment: Si quieres utilizar url "bonitas" para el usuario (por ejemplo, /blog/etiquetas/nombreDeLaEtiqueta) lo que necesitas es filtrar esa URL en el archivo htaccess (depende de cómo tengas montado tu servidor web, a lo mejor necesitas editar otro archivo de configuración diferente, pero vas a necesitar mapear las URL en el archivo de configuración de tu servidor) para que redirija de `/blog/etiquetas/{tagName}` a `etiquetas.php?etiqueta=tagName`, y en php puedes ver el valor del parámetro y devolver lo que quieras. También puedes hacer que blog.php reciba múltiples parámetros directamente :)

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder. Esto es muy complicado pero voy avanzando poco a poco. Yo pensaba que podría crear la consulta con una clausula WHERE con la variable donde tengo la etiqueta guardada, pero no me devuelve nada.
He conseguido hacer lo que habéis dicho , me devuelve esta URL : "etiqueta.php?tagLink=programación" Pero estoy un poco bloqueado con el tema de filtrarlo en el loop. Tengo que modificar la consulta? me va a estallar el coco ^^ y eso que esto es básico! Muchas gracias por la ayuda